# How can I loopback to find an array type field?

Tags: filter, find, loopback

I'm working on `loopback` with `MongoDB`, my model looks like this:

```
{
 "id": "string",
 "managers": [
      "type": ["string"],
      "required": false
  ]
}
```

Now, I want to filter only when second element of the `manager` array (say `manager[1]`) contains a certain string. What should my `where` look like?

Answer (score 1):

Try this
`{"where":{"managers":{"inq":["string"]}}}`.